# Laravel: Which one is better to "reset" a table: ->truncate() or ->delete()?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, transactions, query-builder

I'm using `->truncate()` to delete the data, but `DB::rollback()` in a try catch doesn't executed when I use it. Meanwhile the `->delete()` is executed by `DB::rollback()`, but with it my auto increment doesn't reset to 1, I tried to use `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')` after `->delete()` but alter table doesn't supported by `DB::rollback()` too, so I don't know what should I do?

Code 1:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    \DB::table('table_name')->truncate();
    \DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollback();
}
```

Code 2:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    \DB::table('table_name')->delete();
    \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');
    \DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollback();
}
```

TLDR: I want to delete all data in a table and then insert the table with new data starting from id = 1, but those two codes don't work with `DB::rollback()`

Comment: Is there any reason why you want the id to reset to 1?  Does your code rely on this or is there some other reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it myself, by doing this:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    \DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $data[0]['id'])->delete(); // delete it first to avoid id duplicate when inserting, comment this if id is auto increment
    $status = \DB::table('table_name')->insert($data[0]); // to test whenever the insertion is successful or not
    
    if ($status){
        \DB::table('table_name')->delete();
        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');

        \DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
    }
    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for `mysql`

**13.3.2 Statements That Cannot Be Rolled Back
Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.** see this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html)

It is a fairly common SQL Server belief that Truncate Cannot Be Rolled Back Because It Is Not Logged

TRUNCATE is a logged operation, but SQL Server doesn’t log every single row as it TRUNCATEs the table. SQL Server only logs the fact that the TRUNCATE operation happened. It also logs the information about the pages and extents that were deallocated. However, there’s enough information to roll back, by just re-allocating those pages. A log  backup only needs the information that the TRUNCATE TABLE occurred. To restore the TRUNCATE TABLE, the operation is just reapplied. The data involved is not needed during RESTORE (like it would be for a true ‘minimally logged’ operation like a BULK INSERT).

hopefully that is help you

Comment: Is there any reason why you refer to both MySQL and SQL Server?